# Is hydroxychloroquine an anti-psychotic drug?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemical-biology, structural-biology

Is hydroxychloroquine an anti-psychotic drug or psychotic drug?

Answer (score 1):

Hydroxychloroquine certainly crosses the blood/brain barrier and there are reports of it having psychiatric side effects [example here](https://academic.oup.com/rheumap/article/2/suppl_1/rky033.014/5104090). It is not prescribed for psychiatric conditions [details here](https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01611)